# openpyxl 2.6.2 frozen with .xlsx file no error message

Tags: python, openpyxl

(Sorry for my english)
I have a .xls file downloaded from reporting services. I saved it in .xlsx. when I launch the following code:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\cr.xlsx")
print(type(wb))
```

python idle remains frozen.
No errors are shown.
the same code work fine with other file .xlsx.
Can I change some option in the file excel??

thank's in advance

Comment: What do you mean by frozen? How big is the file?

Comment: The file it's big but it doesn't work also with a little part of him

Comment: Does `wb = load_workbook(filename, read_only=True, keep_links=False)` work?

Comment: I tried a file with 46 rows x 15 column with only 3 rows of code. 4 second of processing. But my file have over  20.000 rows and I must do a lot of operations. what I must do for work with big file??